# CMake if(VARIABLE LESS 22) - what if VARIABLE doesn't exist?

Tags: c++, cmake

If I write

```
if(VARIABLE LESS 22)
  .. do some stuff..
else()
  .. do some other stuff..
endif()
```

if VARIABLE has a value less than 22, ".. do some stuff.." is executed, if VARIABLE is equal or greater to 22, ".. do some other stuff.." is executed.

My question: what if VARIABLE is NOT defined?

Will ".. do some other stuff.." be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean in the context of a CMakeLists file, then yes, ".. do some other stuff.." will be executed.

From the docs for [`if`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aif):

> ```
> if(<variable|string> LESS <variable|string>)
> ```
>
> True if the given string or variable's value is a valid number and the inequality or equality is true.

In this case, the variable's value is not a valid number.